# CSS source map less file location

Tags: css, less

I am trying to get css source maps working to point to my less files but its not working. I am wondering, do the less files need to exist in the wwwroot folder for this to work?

```
app
  less
    ...
wwwroot <- This is where the webserver points too
  css
    css.source.maps
```

I am wondering, does the less directory need to be in with wwwroot? If yes, I will update post with how I am trying to use src maps

Comment: This depends on your compiler, are you using the standard one?

Comment: I am using the gulp-less-sourcemap one

Comment: I believe that uses the standard options.  Try defining the Rootpath and Basepath as described here: http://lesscss.org/usage/index.html